# Modding a (user made) function in vba called LINTERP

Tags: vba, function, excel, with-statement

**TL;DR: There are two functions below. They perform the same task, but the top one is supposed to accept a starting point for a range and a count instead of the bottom one which needs a fixed range. The problem is that the top function does not work unless data is placed in the same sheet. This is annoying, and more so since i don't understand why.**

I was relieved when I found that someone had made a decent interpolator for excel, because they can only trend between 2 points and that is just not good enough to fit my measurements.

I decided to modify the formula so it does not use rigid "range" objects but are given a start "cell" (range) and then a count integer of the dimensions of the range.

My data now has to be on the same sheet as the calculation, or else it will not work. Can you please take a look and see why this is?

My function (I have marked a | on the rows I have changed)

```
| Function LINTERPX(x As Double, rXs As Range, rYs As Range, No As Integer) As Variant
| With ThisWorkbook

Dim i       As Long     ' index to rY
Dim dF      As Double   ' interpolation fraction
Dim v       As Variant  ' for each/loop control variable
| Dim rX      As Range
| Dim rY      As Range

   | Set rX = Range(Cells(rXs.Row, rXs.Column), Cells(rXs.Row + No - 1, rXs.Column))
   | Set rY = Range(Cells(rYs.Row, rYs.Column), Cells(rYs.Row + No - 1, rYs.Column))
| End With
  For Each v In Array(rX, rY)
    If v.Areas.Count > 1 Then GoTo Oops
    If v.Rows.Count <> 1 And v.Columns.Count <> 1 Then GoTo Oops
    If WorksheetFunction.Count(v) <> v.Count Then GoTo Oops
Next v
If rX.Count < 2 Then GoTo Oops
If rX.Count <> rY.Count Then GoTo Oops

dFrac x, rX, i, dF, IIf(rX(2).Value2 > rX(1).Value2, 1, -1)

LINTERPX = rY(i).Value2 * (1 - dF) + rY(i + 1).Value2 * dF
Exit Function

Oops:
LINTERPX = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Original:

```
Function LINTERP(x As Double, rX As Range, rY As Range) As Variant

' shg 1997-0606, 2009-0419
'     2009-0604 added option for descending sort

' Linear interpolator / extrapolator
' Interpolates rX to return the value of y corresponding to the given x

' rX and rY must be equal-length vectors
' rX must be sorted (ascending or descending, doesn't matter)

Dim i       As Long     ' index to rY
Dim dF      As Double   ' interpolation fraction
Dim v       As Variant  ' for each/loop control variable

For Each v In Array(rX, rY)
    If v.Areas.Count > 1 Then GoTo Oops
    If v.Rows.Count <> 1 And v.Columns.Count <> 1 Then GoTo Oops
    If WorksheetFunction.Count(v) <> v.Count Then GoTo Oops
Next v
If rX.Count < 2 Then GoTo Oops
If rX.Count <> rY.Count Then GoTo Oops

dFrac x, rX, i, dF, IIf(rX(2).Value2 > rX(1).Value2, 1, -1)
LINTERP = rY(i).Value2 * (1 - dF) + rY(i + 1).Value2 * dF
Exit Function

Oops:
LINTERP = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Too much information. You should cut down your post to keep only the essentials. This will increase your chance of getting help. For guidance, see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The `Set rX = ` and `Set rY` lines are probably causing the problem. `Range` refers to active sheet. Please try `Set rX = rXs.Resize(No , 1)` instead (similar for `rY`)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: I added a TL;DR on top, does that cover it?

Comment: It pretty much does, so why not remove all the non-essential bits. StackOverflow as a community appreciates brevity, not long blog posts.

Comment: Gotcha =) @pnuts I had assumed that when an input of a function is a range, it will accept ranges on another sheet. i.e. Sheet1!e13 or e13 should both work. no?

Comment: @user3964075 that did indeed do it! Thanks all =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue:

> Set rX = and Set rY lines are probably causing the problem. Range refers to active sheet. Please try Set rX = rXs.Resize(No , 1) instead (similar for rY) –  user3964075 50 mins ago

Thank you user3964075!